# Variable assigned in NaN in loop iteration

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate Entropy manually and my variable to store the result gets a NaN value at every iteration. I have the following code snippet in a matlab function -

```
entropy = 0.0;
%Calculating entropy...
for i = 1:size(freq_norm)
    val = freq_norm(i);
    val_log = log2(val);
    mul = val * val_log;
    entropy = entropy - mul;
    disp(['VALUE: ',num2str(entropy)]);
end
```

Here freq_norm is a vector which consists of values which sum to 1 (like a pdf).
I have the exact same snippet in another part of the program which goes 1:6 values and works perfectly. 
I have also printed out all `val, val_log, mul` values and none of them are NaN and print as expected. `mul` contains values which are approximately about -0.05.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of your `freq_norm` vector? I tried `freq_norm = 0.2 * ones(1, 5);` and didn't get any NaNs.

Comment: If `freq_norm` contains a 0, the log will be -Inf, which you then multiply by 0 to get NaN. You need to skip the zeros to compute entropy.

Comment: Turns out it did contain a 0. It has 256 values and I missed checking a couple of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [log2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log2.html) function is returning NaN, probably because at some point you are trying to take the log of 0 (which is -Inf) and multiplying by 0.

See this [example](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/110681-the-answer-is-nan) for reference.